# How to enable SELinux policy module permanently?

Tags: python, selinux

I have an [RHEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) 8.1 system that I use for development, and the system comes with [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) in enforcing mode by default.

On that system I write and run Python scripts with [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), and for some reason I often get alerts in the SELinux Alerts Browser that says:

> SELinux is preventing /usr/libexec/platform-python3.6 from execute
>   access on the file gpgsm.

I don't understand what this means since my simple Python scripts don't call `gpgsm` (not that I know what `gpgsm` is).

The Details dialog says:

```
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'rhsmcertd-worke' --raw | audit2allow -M my-rhsmcertdworke
# semodule -X 300 -i my-rhsmcertdworke.pp
```

The full output of the Details is

```
*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that platform-python3.6 should be allowed execute access on the gpgsm file by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'rhsmcertd-worke' --raw | audit2allow -M my-rhsmcertdworke
# semodule -X 300 -i my-rhsmcertdworke.pp

Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:rhsmcertd_t:s0
Target Context                system_u:object_r:gpg_exec_t:s0
Target Objects                gpgsm [ file ]
Source                        rhsmcertd-worke
Source Path                   /usr/libexec/platform-python3.6
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          [my hostname]
Source RPM Packages           
Target RPM Packages           
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.14.3-20.el8.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Host Name                     [my hostname]
Platform                      Linux [my hostname] 4.18.0-147.8.1.el8_1.x86_64 #1
                              SMP Wed Feb 26 03:08:15 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   2
First Seen                    2020-04-22 16:48:22 BST
Last Seen                     2020-04-22 16:48:22 BST
Local ID                      2114dd0f-4b36-420d-9ad4-617017e8b43d

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1587570502.586:134): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=4916 comm="rhsmcertd-worke" name="gpgsm" dev="dm-0" ino=765660 scontext=system_u:system_r:rhsmcertd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:gpg_exec_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0


Hash: rhsmcertd-worke,rhsmcertd_t,gpg_exec_t,file,execute
```

So I ran the two commands via `sudo` which generated two files: `my-rhsmcertdworke.te` and `my-rhsmcertdworke.pp`. The `semodule -X 300 -i my-rhsmcertdworke.pp` command ran without any errors and when I list enabled modules with `sudo semodule -lstandard`, it indeed lists `my-rhsmcertdworke` among other enabled modules.

However, I still keep getting the same alerts as if I didn't import and enable that module.

By the way, this is the contents of `my-rhsmcertdworke.te` that was generated via the `ausearch -c 'rhsmcertd-worke' --raw | audit2allow -M my-rhsmcertdworke` command:

```
module my-rhsmcertdworke 1.0;

require {
    type gpg_exec_t;
    type root_t;
    type rhsmcertd_t;
    class file { execute open read };
}

#============= rhsmcertd_t ==============
allow rhsmcertd_t gpg_exec_t:file execute;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow rhsmcertd_t root_t:file read;

#!!!! This avc can be allowed using the boolean 'daemons_dump_core'
allow rhsmcertd_t root_t:file open;
```

What did I do wrong such that the same alerts still happen? How do I truly enable this policy module so that it persists? Thank you!

**P.S.** I don't suppose `my-rhsmcertdworke` has to be the name of the policy module, is it safe to change it to something else? *Is there a naming convention for SELinux policy modules?*